# ipad fancybox issue when parent page is table html

Tags: fancybox

The `#fancybox-overlay{width : 100%}` but I find the width of the fancybox is not the exactly same as the width in the safari browser in the ipad, it only has 80% of the width.

I find the problem is that the parent page has a table.

When I delete the table, things are alright. But I don't want to delete it.

So, what must I do to make all things right without deleting table ?  Many thanks!

```
$("#popup").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe','position':'absolute', 'overlayOpacity': '0.8'
 });


 <a id = "popup" href="popup.html"></a>

 <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
<td align="center">
   <table width="962" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><img src="img/spacer.gif" width="36" height="36" /></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: try setting a css `width: 100%` to your table tag

Comment: The table already has this css style

Comment: well, I was guessing but don't have a magic ball so it's hard to help without seeing your actual code (you supposed to include the relevant code in your question)

Comment: I find that if I reduce the img width is fine but I can't reduce it to 100px, how come

Comment: you have a nested table with `width="962"`